# How to pass a string to a custom documentclass for use in pre-compiled preambles in lualatex?

Tags: luatex, documentclass-writing

I've got a heavy class definition and want to modify it for the use with [**precompiled preambles**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55272/precompiled-header-in-lualatex-on-windows).

---

### Minimal example

**preamble.tex**

```
\documentclass{myClass}
\def\preambleloaded{Precompiled preamble loaded.}
```

**main.tex**

```
\ifdefined\preambleloaded\typeout{\preambleloaded}\else\input{preamble}\fi

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

**myClass.cls**

```
\def\filename{myClass}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{scrbook}

\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\@Author}{George Orwell}

\AtBeginDocument{

Hello World! My name is \@Author!
\newline

}
```

To compile the **preamble.tex** I use:

```
lualatex -ini -job-name="main" "&lualatex preamble.tex\dump"
```

and for the **main.tex**

```
lualatex -shell-escape "&main main.tex"
```

in TexStudio with an up-to-date MikTex distribution.

[image]

**Everything works fine so far** and I get

[image]

---

### Actual question

Now I'd like to pass the **Author name** to the class by defining/redefining it in the preamble, something like this:

**preamble.tex**

```
\documentclass[Aldous Huxley]{myClass}
\def\preambleloaded{Precompiled preamble loaded.}
```

or

```
\documentclass{myClass}
\renewcommand{\@Author}{Aldous Huxley}
\def\preambleloaded{Precompiled preamble loaded.}
```

### How can I do that?

[**I've also seen this question**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43378/how-to-pass-a-string-to-a-class), but can't manage to apply it to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{myClass}
\renewcommand{\@Author}{Aldous Huxley}
\def\preambleloaded{Precompiled preamble loaded.}
```

would work if `@` was a letter at that point (which it isn't here)
or simpler just use the class defined `\Author` command.

This will work:

**preamble.tex**

```
\documentclass{myClass}
\Author{Aldous Huxley}
\def\preambleloaded{Precompiled preamble loaded.}
```

**myClass.cls**

```
\def\filename{myClass}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{scrbook}

\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\@Author}{George Orwell}
\newcommand*{\Author}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@Author}{#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{

Hello World! My name is \@Author!
\newline

}
```